# How to put row which started with letter to row above which started with digit

Tags: regexp-replace

Please help me with regex. This text below

```
07.00   Tom and Jerry
08.00   She is Just Like Others
**Series about young girl...**
09.00   Regional
09.30   Narava zdravi tržnica – Mic Mengeš, oddaja o zdravju
10.00   POP Hits
**Best music all over the world**
11.00   Alaska
12.00   Sport News
**All actual news from sports all over the world**
13.00   Morning news
```

must be:

```
07.00   Tom and Jerry
08.00   She is Just Like Others**...Series about young girl...**
09.00   Regional
09.30   Narava zdravi tržnica – Mic Mengeš, oddaja o zdravju
10.00   POP Hits**...Best music all over the world**
11.00   Alaska
12.00   Sport News**...All actual news from sports all over the world**
13.00   Morning news
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Notepad++, you can match the line that starts with the time like pattern. Then forget what is matched so far with `\K` and match the newline with `\R` that you want to remove.

Match `**` on the next line.

In the replacement use `**...`

```
^\d{2}\.\d{2}\b.*\K\R\*\*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sDJoxx/1)

[image]

Comment: don't work...is problem maybe because between digit and text is always tab 
07.00 \t Tom...

Comment: @webmaher That does not matter in this case, see https://regex101.com/r/0M4w3h/1. Can you create a regex101 link with the text you have in notepad++ and then share it here in the comments? Just to be sure, did you select "Regular expression" ?

Comment: here is my real text: https://regex101.com/r/RduNBw/1

Comment: @webmaher But with that text from the question this works in my Notepad++ v8.5.4 What is your version? You could try it without the anchor `\d{2}\.\d{2}.*\K\R\*\*` Do you see any selection at all? What do you see when you search for `\d.*` and replace with an empty string?

Comment: @webmaher That text does not contain `**` at all right?

Comment: yes, but sometimes does

Comment: @webmaher But if you give me an example regex101 link without the actual relevant parts, then I can not test it right? :-)

Comment: without ancor i got nothing https://i.imgur.com/dWOCSK9.jpg and with \d.* almost all rows disappear https://i.imgur.com/RQA5iv3.jpg  now i have new version Notepad ++

Comment: @webmaher Can't you create a regex101 example link with the real text that you are trying to match including the `**` ?

Comment: here is complet text in zip file https://lotosistemi.net/osnova1.zip

Comment: @webmaher That file also does not contain `**` in the text. You can see that if a manually add it, that the replacement still works. https://regex101.com/r/pO8WdI/1

Comment: yes you right..if add ** this work...can you please rewrite that work without **

Comment: @webmaher I am not sure what you want then, but if you want to remove the newlines before the lines that do not start with a time https://regex101.com/r/oIGTox/1

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.online-python.com/ you can copy paste your content in the text variable bellow:

```py
import re

text = '''07.00   Tom and Jerry
08.00   She is Just Like Others
**Series about young girl...**
09.00   Regional
09.30   Narava zdravi tržnica – Mic Mengeš, oddaja o zdravju
10.00   POP Hits
**Best music all over the world**
11.00   Alaska
12.00   Sport News
**All actual news from sports all over the world**
13.00   Morning news
'''

pattern = r'(\d{2}\.\d{2}.*\S)\n(\*\*.*\*\*)'
replacement = r'\1**...\2**'

result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)
print(result)
```

result:

```py
    
07.00   Tom and Jerry
08.00   She is Just Like Others**...**Series about young girl...****
09.00   Regional
09.30   Narava zdravi tržnica – Mic Mengeš, oddaja o zdravju
10.00   POP Hits**...**Best music all over the world****
11.00   Alaska
12.00   Sport News**...**All actual news from sports all over the world****
13.00   Morning news
```

Comment: this pattern and replacement dont work in my Notepad ++

Comment: I recommend using Python for this solution. If you're seeking a one-time solution, consider using https://www.online-python.com/. You can easily copy and paste the content there to obtain your result.

Comment: On notepad ++, you might need a different approach due to its regex engine limitations. 

Maybe that can works: `(\d{2}\.\d{2}.*\S)\r?\n(\*\*.*\*\*)`
replace with `\1**...\2**`